# DndSimulator is not defined when using drag and drop on HTML5

Tags: c#, html, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with selenium webDriver with C# on Windows for automating tests with HTML5 drag and drop. Also, I use `dragTo` (This is only one solution which works for me) method from Selenium. The first test runs successfully but any other tests going to fail if I change the WebPage and back again to the page with drag and drop. And I get an error

It's the same for older chrome webDrivers

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error:
>   DndSimulator is not defined   (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)

Can some one help me with this issue?

Comment: At first glance it seems to be a reference to the classical roleplaying game Dungeons and Dragons (which sounds stupid now that its written down)... do you know of a function by that name?

Answer (score 0):

You need reset DragAndDropExtension.
Before next to use "DragAndDropExtension.DragTo".
try this:

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(DragAndDropExtension).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[0], null);
constructor.Invoke(null, null);
```